# integrate paypal for payment over the phone

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway

1. Agent receives booking and - over an API - sends a payment request to the client's paypal address.
2. When payment arrives, an IPN is sent to our server for confirmation.

For this to work, request and payment would need to be linked to an ID (i.e. TXN-ID)

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check out their Invoicing API:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Here is what you'll want to do.

1. Submit an app for REST APIs - steps [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/)
2. Make sure you APP is set for API Invoicing - [steps here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/invoicing/) **(note section)**
3. Next SDK sample code to guide you along the way - [steps here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/invoicing/)

In Short the invoicing API is the best method for over the phone payment request to paypal account orders